# i want some changes in total price of grouped products in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, product, price

i'm working on grouped products price now total price is calculated as

**Total price = product(a) price x product(a) quantity + product(b) price x product() quantity**

i want some change in that calculation like this

**Total price = product(a) price x product(a) quantity x product(a) Carton + product(b) price x product(b) quantity x product(b) Carton**

anyone can tell me where is code or how to do it

Comment: Where in admin are you defining "product(a) Carton"? Is it a product attribute?

Comment: YES it is an attribute . i have 3 diffrenet carton size with different price of each carton set 
for example
Quantity per Carton |  Price PER Carton   |
                       1-2  | 3-6  | 6+
______________________________________________
   23               |   $30  | $25 | $20  |

Comment: complete problem is here 
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34270/how-to-create-a-configurable-product-and-add-tier-prices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i override  calcRowTotal function and it's working for me

```
public function calcRowTotal()
    {


        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $product->load($product->getId());
         $QuantityPerCarton_get = $product->getQuantityPerCarton();
         if(!empty($QuantityPerCarton_get)) {
            $QuantityPerCarton  = $QuantityPerCarton_get;
         }
         else {
             $QuantityPerCarton =1;
         }

        $qty        = $this->getTotalQty();
        if ($qty <= 3) 
        {
            $price = $product->getPricePerCorton();
        }
        elseif(3 <  $qty && $qty >= 5) 
        {
            $price = $product->getPricePerCortonSecond();
        }
        elseif(5 <  $qty )  {
            $price = $product->getPricePerCortonThree();
        }
        else  {
            $price = $this->getStore()->roundPrice($this->getCalculationPriceOriginal());
        }
        // Round unit price before multiplying to prevent losing 1 cent on subtotal
       $total      =   $qty * $price *  $QuantityPerCarton;
        $baseTotal  = $this->getStore()->roundPrice($this->getBaseCalculationPriceOriginal()) * $qty * $price  * $QuantityPerCarton;

        $this->setRowTotal($this->getStore()->roundPrice($total));
        $this->setBaseRowTotal($this->getStore()->roundPrice($baseTotal));
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use configurable products to change price depending on product attribute.

In you case you can create a grouped product, which consists of configurable products, each of which has a "Carton" attribute and a different price set depending on the attribute value.

Comment: i have created attributes with carton set with different price but on click add to cart ...system calculate final cost as product price x quantity ..
but i need final cost  as  Quantity per Carton x Price PER Carton  X Quantity

Comment: Are you using a configurable product?

Comment: I'm using grouped products with those attributes